# Need help in understanding the below plot generated using randomForestExplainer library in R

Tags: r, random-forest

[image: Relaion between rankings according to different measures.]

I am not able to understand what this plot depicts and what we mean by the relation between rankings.Let me add a few more things to make it a bit precise. This plot is generated by using `plot_importance_rankings` function available as part of `randomForestExplainer` package.

A sample code which generates this code is as

```
plot_importance_rankings(var_importance_frame)
```

where `var_importance_frame` contains important variables which we get as from

```
var_importance_frame <- measure_importance(rf_model)
```

Here `rf_model` is the trained random forest model. A sample example can be found at this link [RandomForestExplainer - sample example](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/randomForestExplainer/vignettes/randomForestExplainer.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about R code but even in Cross Validated it would be considered too broad.

Comment: Let me add a few more things to make it a bit precise. This plot is generated by using plot_importance_rankings function available as part of randomForestExplainer library. A sample code which generates this code is as plot_importance_rankings(var_importance_frame): where var_importance_frame contains important variables which we get as from var_importance_frame <- measure_importance(rf_model). Here rf_model is the trained random forest model.

Comment: OK, then edit the question with that information, please. And in order to make the example reproducible, include minimal code to produce `rf_model`. For instance, can you use a package example?

Comment: have edited the question and added the details. Also have added a link where a detail sample code with plot is available. Lemme know if I am missing something or few more details are required from me.

Comment: Much better. Anyway, this is a question about results interpretation and therefore off-topic here at SO, can you repost to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)? I will retract my colse vote, btw. But I now believe it should be migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `randomForestExplainer` package implements several measures to assess a given variable's importance in the random forests models. On this plot, you have mean_min_depth (average minimum depth of a variable across all trees), accuracy_decrease (accuracy loss by randomly permuting on a given variable), gini_decrease (average gain of purity by splitting on a given variable), no_of_nodes (number of nodes that split on a given variable across trees), times_a_root (number of times a given variable is used as the root of trees). Ideally you'd want these importance measures to be somewhat consistent, in that a variable measured as of high importance by one metric is also measured high by the others. What this plot is showing is this as a sanity check. In your case the variable importances are largely consistent and positively correlated. Each dot on the scatter plot represents a variable.